# how to give custom validation in django and djangorestframework on creating an API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my question I am creating address model, in that city, district I am accepting null values, Because for some API View I will accept Null values, but another API I will call this same models that time I want to validate that field is required, How Its is possible Here is my below code example.

```
models.py
class Address(models.Model):
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('Cities', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    district = models.ForeignKey('Districts', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class Assignaddress(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class dont`Assignaddress(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now in serializer.py

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('address_line1','address_line2','city','district')

class AssignaddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = Assignaddress
            fields = ('address ','owner_name ')

class dont`AssignaddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = dont`Assignaddress
            fields = ('address ','owner_name ')
```

now How can I validate Assignaddress you have to pass city and district is required and don`tAssignaddress its not neccessary

Sorry for not writting views.py

Comment: is my solution what you are looking for or did I missunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

So in one of your serializers you want to accept null values? You can do this with `allow_null` and / or `required` (for fields that should not be supplied during deserialization). Be sure to check out the corresponding Django Rest Framework [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null).

Example (out of my memory - check Django Rest Framework documentation for specific use case):

```
class AssignaddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Assignaddress
        fields = ('address ','owner_name ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, I just want to know from the foreign key relations how can I be set that city and district field is required = True or any sample code is there for the reference is better for me to understand

Comment: @Gowtham Still I am not sure if I understand you correctly - I edited my answer and gave you an example for a PrimaryKeyRelatedField that allows null values passed to the serializer.